How do you tip cash when you don't have proper denomination or no cash at all?
Many countries have moved to cashless payment systems to the point where the need for cash has almost been entirely eliminated. On a recent trip to 3 countries in Europe I used cash only twice (parking meter and one card machine at the museum was broken).
At the same time expectation around scope and amount of tipping is going up everywhere. Even in countries that used to be tip free lots of people now expect tips for most interactions. The expectation is often a cash tip. For example one tour provider in South Africa gave clear instruction: you are expected to tip, you should tip every person individually right when the interaction happens, and you should tip in cash. Since South Africa is mostly a cash free country, pretty much 100% of our cash expense was tip.
That creates a difficult situation for the traveler. Cash is highly undesirable: it's expensive, often difficult to get, easy to lose or get stolen, hard to track, and sometimes outright dangerous. Ironically most websites strongly discourage carrying cash in South Africa.
A related problem is not having the right denominations. For example in India ₹100 is convenient tip but the smallest thing that comes out of an ATM (even if you find a working one) is ₹500. Banks are hard to find and many merchants refuse to make change or pretend they don't have any (so they can keep the change). If you happen to have some ₹100 bills in the morning, by 11:00am you are out.
Overall this has become a major nuisance with awkward situations and mad scrambles to find an ATM and/or get correct change.
Questions

What are best practices to deal with cash tips when otherwise you don't need cash at all?
How to get proper "tipping cash" cost effective, safely and efficiently?
Any tips or tricks or best practices are welcome to.


While it's certainly an interesting question, I think there's going to be a list of answers for different situations/countries rather than a single right answer (example: in some countries where USD is widely used and more stable than the local currency, tip in USD for which small notes are fairly easy to get - or at least that was true in a few places 10+ years ago). So I'm not sure how the answers can be sorted.

The usual method to get the smaller notes/coins is to go buy something cheap (a drink for instance), pay with a relatively large bill, and ask for as much change of the type you want as they are willing. But I can see that becoming a problem as they have less and less cash (and in some places cash manipulation is automated). There are a few places where you can find change machines (insert a note and get smaller notes or coins). Laudromats used to have those for instance, no idea if that's still the case (and it's not always easy to find out).

Cash is not always expensive. In fact, I have over the last years more and more often gone back to using cash instead of cards when going abroad. Particularly in non-euro East-European countries (e.g. Czechia, Poland, Romania, Serbia, Bulgaria), exchange offices usually give me a better exchange rate for buying local currency with euros, than my (German) bank would give me if I pay by card.

(in re denominations issue) Just say "can you change this 20 for me...", it's understood to mean that you want to tip.

In Guatemala, US dollars generally will not work.  The banks will only accept, near perfect, $20 bills, no creases, no folded corners, no writing, etc.
Restaurants which expects tips here in Guatemala generally include the tip automatically and we always pay in credit card, debit cards will often have fees.
Thankfully, at the airport, you can often change American bills for local bills.  I've never had an issue carrying small amounts of cash.  The upscale hotels often have safes in your room, although you may need a manager to help you open it and set a combination.

In the UK there are very few places where a tip would be appropriate that don't let you use your card, either as part of the main payment, or as part of a small payment tip machine. Also, tips here are less of an issue, as service staff are not reliant on them like they would be in eg the US.

Move to NZ. Tipping is very largely unknown here. Largely salary / wage systems are adequate to make tipping other than the dire necessity it is in mamy countries. eg when tips of say 10% or 15% are inclued in the bill as of right it's just the mamagement rearranging the paymet system. || That said, I try to ensure that I always carry a small amount of cash so that I can donate some to various people along the way (usually not tips.)

I can't speak to how it works in other countries, but here in Mexico we usually just ask them if they can make change for a larger amount.  If they're receiving cash tips already, they usually are quite able and happy to (in fact I can't remember anyone ever saying "no").

Can you make change for $200?  Keep $50 as tip.

As for when we don't have cash we simply apologise and tell them we have no cash, or we head to a nearby ATM and ask if they can make change for $200.
Mexico (or at least Tijuana, where we live) is predominantly a cash society though, so we almost always have some cash on us.

Same experience in the US. This benefits the tip recipient as they can get rid of some of their smaller bills for larger ones.

They are receiving a tip, refusing to change money for it works be outright stupid.

Although it's been some time since I've had the issue (almost everything is electronic and contactless at that), I usually do something like:
(handing a $50 bill), "just give me a ten back" or "small change please" (the latter basically tells them that you are intending to tip and if they bring back a $20 and coins when the tip should be $10 or $12, they stand a fairly high chance of being left with only the coins, especially since you specifically requested it).
If you're in a place that deals in cash, it's a bit more effort, each time you buy something small use a large bill until you have a comfortable amount of cash in large/small/medium denominations (and don't let the clerk see your stash of small bills or they may ask for the small bills). Usually they'd prefer to make the change rather than lose the sale. And as you are leaving, it's the same thing in reverse- pay for larger purchases with wads of low-denomination bills until you're down to an amount you can exchange, donate or keep as a souvenir. When you are exchanging, the foreign notes they have are usually fairly large denomination so you might want to roughly calculate the remaining amount so you can get the maximum in the foreign currency.
I don't have a solution for crooked taxi drivers that pretend to be unable to make change, fortunately Didi, Uber, Grab, BiTaksi, Bolt, Cabify, HKTaxi, Loca etc. have made that problem go away permanently. On the other hand, if you ever do have to use cash they may well not have change. I guess you could ask them to stop at a convenience store or whatever but if they're taking you to the airport there might not be anything like that easily available, so better to be careful to avoid that situation. If a tip is involved and more-or-less mandatory, it's usually acceptable enough to give them the tip in some other widely accepted currency such as Euro, USD or that of a friendly neighboring country. Nobody wants your ratty USD $1 bills though in many places overseas though, crisp and larger denomination bills only.

It depends.
Excursions, bus, guides, etc.: you get clear instruction in advance, so you can prepare some cash. Note: and now it is also frequent that they allow contactless tips (depending on how easier would be for people to pay more tips).
Else: just ask to add in the bill: some machines requires you select the tip (or no tip) before finalizing the payment. But in such case, you may want to do some search on Internet about customs on each country: some countries have bad employees which do not distribute fairly the tip, so you may need to prepare some cash (OTOH you may see that the tips will be put in the tip pot, so it will be shared anyway, and hopefully fairly).
As last resource: no tip: you didn't get the "service of the tip". In fact it seems that tipping is reducing. (but check customs for target country, and also considering the wages).

This does not seem to address the OP's question. It's specifically about places where you need to tip in cash (i.e. excuses about tipping on the card or service levels are irrelevant) and “prepare some cash” begs the entire question.

I found in Ireland that waiters were often not allowed to put tip on a card. Cash tip only.  I have never seen a service person accepting cashless tip unless it already involves a cashless transaction.

@Relaxed: my experience: if they want tip in cash, they tell you in advance. It is their interest. If you do not have cash and they requires tip in cash... just they do not get tip. Is it obvious? I cannot print cash. Is the question: how to get cash if I do not have cash? I see more: how to deal if I do not have cash and they want cash (so the cash option is not available)

@GiacomoCatenazzi The question is indeed how to get small banknotes when paying less and less in cash but Midavalo's answer is a good example of how to reframe the problem in a useful way. On the other hand, “just they do not get tip. Is it obvious? I cannot print cash” is neither an answer nor a reasonable thing to say. Would you also just walk about without paying because you cannot make a credit card? You're just rehashing the usual self-serving excuses without addressing the question.

@Relaxed: I do not see in such way. If I see on front door that I can pay with cards, I do not expect I need cash for tips. Again: usually they write in advance if the tips should be on cash (likes on some excursions). Else I find myself cheated (like when they say they accept cards, and magically the card reader doesn't work: you just tell them you have cards or just a small bill and magically the card machine work again: it happens a lot). So if they accept cards, I expect either something explicit on tips or it is acceptable not giving tips (which now in Europe seems to be in declining).

As tourist, we get cheated many time (also with tips), and as you can see, there are many way to overcome that (add tip to the bill, or tips separately). Do not think that waiters are always honest with tourists. We offer a solution, it is in their hand to decide: they want the tip or not. No excuse, or write it in advance about special requirement on tips (like many places do).

@GiacomoCatenazzi I know you don't (want to) see it that way, that's what I called a self-serving excuse. You can chose to ignore local customs and reality, it doesn't really change anything (or the question). It's hypocritical and disingenuous to pretend you're offering a real choice to people who depend on tips to get a livable wage. But if you don't like that reality, you don't need to engage with the question. Meanwhile, you're not offering any useful suggestions.

@GiacomoCatenazzi where I live in Mexico I can pay by card in some restaurants or grocery stores etc., but almost all tips are cash only.  Very rare for tips to be included (or an option to include) in the card charge.

@Relaxed it for sure is different depending on countries and culture, so the answer here may work in some places but not in others. OTOH, as much as I try to adapt to local culture when traveling, I don‘t see it solely as my responsibility to ensure that staff is adequately payed. If a place offers cashless payment but expects tips to be payed in cash, things become difficult.

@nohillside Exactly and that's the gist of the question…

@Relaxed Not sure I understand why you attack this answer then, though. It basically says the same.

@nohillside Because “If a place offers cashless payment but expects tips to be payed in cash, things become difficult” is where the question starts from. I can agree with that comment but just repeating it and adding a lot of self-serving excuses why you don't want to be bothered just isn't an answer.


What are best practices to deal with cash tips when otherwise you don't need cash at all?

The best practice is to NOT tip, that works everywhere.

How to get proper "tipping cash" cost effective, safely and efficiently?

By not tipping, you act most cost efficient, safe (cause you have no cash) and most efficiently overall.

Any tips or tricks or best practices are welcome to.

Stop tipping, hope that helps.

In some countries (USA maybe more) the employer has to pay less if the workers earn a living salary out of tips. If everyone stops tipping that would stop and prices would be adjusted to make up. But if only you stop you just deny the person money everybody expects them to get.

Someone has to make the 1. step then... ;)

Funny how this gets downvoted when this is essentially the same answer than Giacomo's, just a little more blunt and without trying to obfuscate what you really are doing.

@Relaxed Even if one agrees that a world without tips and properly priced items would be a better world, in the practical real world in a lot of places this answer essentially amounts to 'just be an asshole'.

@quarangue Yes, clearly and that's just not what the OP is asking about, it's just that Giacomo pretty much advocates the same thing and gets a handful of upvotes...

@quarague Why is someone an "asshole" if he doesn't pay for something he wasn't priced for? I just don't understand that logic...

@goulashsoup You may not like it but you will be perceived that way. Feel free to try it out if you don't believe it.

@Relaxed I fail to see how Giacomo's answer is advocating the same thing as this one.  This answer says "Never tip".  That one says "Here's a suggestion, and if it doesn't work, don't tip".  That's very different.
